# How to centre font-awesome icons within <a> tag and disable link colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to centre a font-awesome within an  tag and disable the blu colour but so far I have not succeed in my aim.
In addition I wish to have the icon a bit larger but the maximum size supported in font-awesome is 5x.

Could you please help me out with these issues
Thanks

To reproduce the problem please visit the link below
https://jsfiddle.net/z0vvpddf/

**HTML**

```
   <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item ">
        <a href="<c:url value='/'></c:url>" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"> 
          <span class="caption"> 
              <span class="caption-content"> 
                <i>Wall</i>
              </span>
             </span> 
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#portfolio .portfolio-item 
{
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link 
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #004DFA;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption:hover 
{
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content i 
{
    margin-top: -12px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h3,
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h4 
{
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio * 
{
    z-index: 2;
}

@media(min-width:767px) 
{
    #portfolio .portfolio-item 
    {
        margin: 0 0 30px;
    }
}

img.displayed 
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

Comment: Please be much mor concise about what you want to achieve. For example you have text in your link ("Wall"), what should happen with tthat?

Comment: The text must stay where it is. I want the icon in the back to be centred, a bit bigger and black.

Comment: So you want the icon behind the text?

Comment: Yes Please. That is what I want. The image must remain the same size but bigger. When I go with the mouse over the image I should see a blue hover with the text wall. Both of them centred

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z0vvpddf/2/

Comment: @connexo Thanks you very much indeed. I managed to fix it using your solution.

Comment: @connexo if you write you answer I am going to accept it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your solution in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0vvpddf/2/

```
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .fa-home {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Font Icons can be controlled the same way regular fonts are.  You can use `color` `font-size` and `text-align` css properties to style them for your purpose, as well as `text-shadow` and other text-specific styling.

Modifcation on connexo's fiddle to remove underline on hover and increase the font (icon) size:

https://jsfiddle.net/4za5y63s/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer your questions one at a time:

1. How to center the icon? I added the following CSS to the selector you already have.

   `&#35;portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
       text-align: center;
   }`

   `&#35;portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption {
       left: 0;
   }`

   `&#35;portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content {
       left: 0;
   }`
2. How do I increase the size of the icon? You can create what your own css to do this by setting the font-size. Font-awesome uses `em` units, so `.fa-5x` is just `5em`.

   `.fa-7x {
       font-size: 7em;
   }`
3. How do I change the color? To change the color of the `<a>`,

   `&#35;portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
       color: green;
   }`

to change the color of the icon,

```
`&#35;portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .fa {
    color: red;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {color: #000;}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link:hover {color: #fff;}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link:hover .fa {font-size: 10em;} /* 10x */
```

#### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/z0vvpddf/1/

Check this, may be?

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.portfolio-link, .portfolio-link:hover {color: #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
      <a href="#" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
        <span class="caption pull-right"> 
          <span class="caption-content">Wall</span>
        </span> 
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not there yet. This overrides the opacity I set before which covers totally the image. In addition does not centre the image

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Check now?

Comment: Still does not work. I managed to solve the issue changing few lines using connexo  link jsfiddle.net/z0vvpddf/2 Thanks a lot